# Bash prevent symbol expansion when reading from STDIN

Tags: bash, quotes

I'm writing a bash script that will receive a password via `STDIN` and go through a few different checks.

I'm getting a problem when I use a password that contain symbols.

The plain password `grassy` is OK, but a complex combination such as `gra$$y` will expand to `gra3308y`.

This is the script I am using:

```
read INPUT

if [ $(echo -n $INPUT|wc -m) -ge 6 ]

then exit 0
else exit 1

fi
```

I've tried all different kinds of quotations but I can't stop the `STDIN` password from expanding special characters.

Here is an example, without putting single quotes around the original value what can be done to solve this?

```
david@hostname ~ $ echo gra$$| { read INPUT; echo ${INPUT}; }
gra2598
```

Comment: It's not the stdin that's expanding it, it's the shell on the invocation of 'echo' ... one possible way is to store it into a temp file and `shred -u` that file. Another would be to apply `eval` and `sed` in sneaky ways ...

Comment: Actually your original script that reads from STDIN works fine when one enters `gra$$` on STDIN but of course your test command expands `$$` before it is even read in INPUT variable.

Comment: Also note that `read` eats backslashes in the input unless you use `-r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes around variable expansions inside your script:

```
read INPUT
echo "Password was: $INPUT"
if [ $(echo -n "$INPUT" | wc -m) -ge 6 ]
then echo "OK"; exit 0
else echo "Bogus"; exit 1
fi
```

While you're developing a script, use `echo` to show what you're working with, but also use double quotes.

If you type a line at this program, there will be no shell expansion done on the characters you type.  If you simulate a user typing with `echo`, then you need to prevent the shell that executes the `echo` from expanding any metacharacters, thus:

```
echo 'gra$$' | bash yourscript
```

Omitting the single quotes means that the shell will replace the `$$` with a PID (probably the PID of the parent shell rather than the shell in the pipeline, but with some PID).  This is different from you typing 5 characters plus newline after running:

```
bash yourscript
```

You could also use:

```
$ cat > password-file
gra$$
<control-D>
$ cat password-file
gra$$
$ bash yourscript < password-file
```

The `<control-D>` is the EOF indication; it flushes all zero characters typed since the last newline was entered, and `cat` interprets zero bytes available as EOF. The file therefore contains 6 characters: the letters '`g`', '`r`', '`a`', two '`$`' signs and a newline.  This will be read by your script verbatim; there will be no expansion on the data.

Comment: Just gave it a shot and it's working. I see what you mean about the echo expansion, it's been causing me much confusion. Thanks so much for taking the time to explain it!

Comment: You can also use `set -f` to disable globbing altogether for some commands and enable it back again ...